# Mudar texto de TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Tenho um TextView ao qual uso uma String como o texto, queria saber se é possível através de um click mudar essa String(texto) para um novo texto que for digitado.

```
public class Texto extends Activity {
TextView Txtmessage;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
setContentView( R.layout.texto );

Txtmessage = (TextView)  findViewById( R.id.EdtMensagemCalendar );
Txtmessage.setText( Txt );
Txtmessage.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
} );
}
```

Queria saber se dentro de OnClick tem como eu criar uma opção para o usuário digitar a mensagem que quiser e assim mudar a String(Txt).

Comment: Sim. Você criar um dialog que será criado e exibido ao clicar em TextMessage. Nesse dialog há um botão e um textEdit. O usuário informa o texto e clica no botão e nesse momento você altera o texto.

Comment: Obrigado. Como seria esse código?